# Performing heavy functions on the client and side effects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I have a few heavy functions in the program which, for example, may take some time to complete (<.2s and > 1s). These pure functions, but i do not want to delay the main flow of the application with computing. Where will it be more correct to call it? I thought in **mapDispatchToProps**, in the selector (output of the function is stored in the store), but again this will all be done **synchronously**, **as I understand**. In **AC** it seems to me to do it wrong, although the **function is clean**.

- Now I do it in **middleware** (computing on the client’s side, but **this is not a side effect** or **what**?)

**next(action)** in the **middleware** first simply sets a flag at the beginning of the computing, and then calls inside the **MW** function that returns **Promise**, when the function has complete, it **dispatch** data to the store and sets the flag (calculate is done). I feel that this approach **is not entirely correct**. Any thoughts on that?

- What if the average function calculation time were > **1s**?

### The function is **CLEAN**, and must computing **ONLY** on the client

**Now** i call this pure func in **middleware**

```
export default (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  const { computeSomeData, type, ...rest } = action

  if (!computeSomeData) return next(action)

  store.dispatch({
    type: type + START,
    ...rest
  })

  someAsyncFunc(computeSomeData)
    .then(
      response => store.dispatch({...})
      error => store.dispatch({...})
  )
}
```

- It's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your approach is correct. Middleware ist excatly there place for these side effects. You call an action and update the state asynchronous with the newly computed data after it is done in a none blocking way. So thats best practice. Regarding your mapStateToProps comment. You should keep your state as small as possible and don't keep duplicated data. So if your computed Data is derived from actual data in the store and saving the computed data will create a second source of truth, you should move the calculation into a selector, which is called in mapStateToProps. To prevent unnecessary computations and to prevent lagging, should should memorize the output. For example with reselect or memoize-one.
Hope this helps. Happy coding

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if I will compute some data in selectors (with reselect which I'm already using), I think there may be a lag if the function will be executed for a long time. What do you think about this? If for example in the selector place function which will be calculated about 1 sec, how will this affect the main flow of the application? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and [web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) to achieve that.

You will be dispatching an action that will be captured by the redux-saga code and then compute your thing on a new thread using the webworker so the thread of your app will run ok. When the webworker finished, your code on the redux-saga will dispatch a new action with the result, and the reducer on react-redux will act.

Comment: My code is working fine. Can you explain why i need to use this library? My question was whether this is the right approach. I can paste these functions into component and all continue work. But what if I need to run other functions with a larger computing time. How much is the right decision to use large asynchronous functions in middleware (which work on the client )?

Comment: The use of these library is because of the lags you were describing. web-workers will allow you to run long calculations without affect the main UI thread so there will not be lag on your app, it will be responsinve even when doing the calculation. And redux-saga is one of many ways to do side-effects on a redux approach of an app, so it will be calling your calculation method and wait for it. @ElmoKennedy